# Community wiki button overlaps blockquote and "draft saved" message is misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, answers, design

These are two problems I've experienced on a desktop with the new SO design. The first is that the community wiki button is on top of a written blockquote:

[image]

The second is that when I save a draft for a question the "draft saved" message appears in a weird place:

[image]

This also goes for the "draft saved" message on the answer box as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. The change will be on live after the next production build.